# solution for hosted images on big portal

Tags: php, nginx

I'm taking into consideration now, as I have few more steps upon completion on my portal website, the hosting of images.

Most of my 1-2 first years, the images + http daemon (nginx) + mysql database will be hosted on 1 VPS. But after that, while traffic increases, I will need to move to other solution, including scaling (mysql as well as balancing nginx).

My 1st thought which i'm implementing right now in the website is add a variable like $global_server_pictures_address in front of the "/folder/1/123.jpg", where this is one of the images uploaded, which will change from $global_server_pictures_address = ""; to

```
$global_server_pictures_address = "http://195.22.31.14".
```

This means (nginx) will be balanced with few more VPS'es which will server local content, and for each nginx VPS, when it's a query for an image, it will load from $global_server_pictures_address.

Another ideea that came to me would be, in the case of multiple VPS serving the website (nginx balanced), each time a user uploads an image, he would do it via curl php function (FTP_UPLOAD), on each server I have, this way reducing some bandwidth stress on the main 50Mbps VPS image server, now if we have say 3 VPS with each 50Mbps, and all holding the images, each with same stuff, balancing would be not good for nginx but also for bandwidth.
In this case, my $global_server_pictures_address will go away, we don't need it anymore.

I'm waiting for some other ideeas (if you have any) and also comments on my ideeas, what do you think of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use AWS S3 to to store the images, that way all of your front-end server would have access to them, there would be a cost associated for image storage and bandwidth.

You also have CloudFront (AWS CDN) if you wanted better performance.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/